# What does "in keeping for" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Quite unexpectedly, the 2008 WDR picked a theme perfectly in keeping for a world once again worring over food security in the face of rising food prices.

Hear is the source:

Development Econonics through Decades, Shahid Yusuf, page 44.

https://openknowledge.worldbank.org/handle/10986/2586

Comment: What is the source? I think this should have been [*in keeping with*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/in-keeping-with), which is a common phrase.

Comment: This is a mistake for *in keeping **with***, which you may find in a dictionary such as [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-keeping-with).

Comment: Shahid Yusuf is not an English speaker, so mistakes of this sort are to be expected.